# Automate website project startup process

Tags: windows-7, browser, automation

I work on many client's websites on different days and want to know if there is a way to automate the process of switching between projects. In other words...

- Sublime should open, close the last project and open the new project
- Google Chrome should shut down and open the new user profile
- Google chrome should open all the right tabs .i.e.

  - Localhost website
  - Localhost dashboard (of WordPress)
  - Log into dashboard
  - Localhost Xampp
  - Live site front end
  - Live site dashboard (of WordPress)
  - Log into dashboard
- Open Windows Explorer to the right website project folder
- Open Windows Explorer to the right client folder
- Align two explorer windows next to one another on the right (or left) monitor.
- Open Adobe Bridge in the right project folder

I don't know about anyone else but this takes up a lot of my time during any given day.
If someone could make a recommendation as to the best way to tackle this, I would appreciate the input.

I use Windows 7 Pro

Comment: Can't you do many of these from a batch/command file, maybe use powershell (you're not saying which Windows version)? You'd have to experiment with startup parameters and such, but then you can ask specific questions about individual programs. As it is, your question is quite broad.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I added my OS too. I am going to have a look into batch files now.